# How to rotate source of image and not image itself in C#/XAML(WPF 8.1)?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, bitmap, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a painting app for windows phone 8.1 and I'm stuck. I have a working space (bitmap) that I'm able to rotate and a stamp control with which I can stamp drawed Elements. The stamp control consists of a rectangle and an image inside this rectangle. If the working space is on 0 or 180 degrees there is no problem for me to visualize the stamped elements inside the image. The problem appears if the working space is rotated by 90 or 270 degrees. Than if I rotate the image by the degrees of the working space the width and height of the image is obviously postponed.

```
public void SetSourceImageStamp(ImageSource imageSource)
{
    var currentPocketPaintApplication = PocketPaintApplication.GetInstance();
    RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();

    rt.Angle = currentPocketPaintApplication.angularDegreeOfWorkingSpaceRotation;
    image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

    if (currentPocketPaintApplication.angularDegreeOfWorkingSpaceRotation == 90 || currentPocketPaintApplication.angularDegreeOfWorkingSpaceRotation == 270)
    {
        image.Height = RectangleToDraw.Width;
        image.Width = RectangleToDraw.Height;
        image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        image.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    }

    image.RenderTransform = rt;

    image.Source = imageSource;   
}
```

So I have the following question, is there a possibility to rotate only the source of the image and not the whole image itself?

Comment: The only way I can think of, is you can rotate an ImageBrush within a parent panel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem.